# He told me he often felt like he can reach me faster than his own wife - proper past tense?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, conjugation

What I want is to put this into past tense:

`He often feels like he can reach me faster than...` (e.g. his own wife)

1) "He told me that he often felt like he was able to reach me faster than ...", or
2) **"He told me that he often felt like he can reach me faster than ..."**
3) I don't want to use "could", as to my understanding that expresses the possibility - I want to talk about something that did actually happen (and did so often).

My preference would be (2) but I'm struggling about the form or function of the 'can' in this case and whether it should be conjugated or not.

Sorry if this is a repeat (in that case please just point me to where / how to look for it), but it's hard to search for things like this if you don't know the right terminology.
I'm a long time English user but some constructs are still puzzling to me (especially translating things to past tense, I'm aware of the basic rules but I usually end up going more with the 'feeling').
Thanks!

---

What I want to say is this, in the present tense:
(I'll use another real-life example)

`Very often I can reach him before anyone (other employee/people) sitting in my office` (even though he is on the other side of the world)

That I think best describes the intent here - and the **goal is to translate that into past tense**.

Mind that I'm actually having an issue expressing here in the best way, so if you have a construct that is a better fit please do suggest (as I'm aware that often what sounds good in the present-tense should actually be reworded rather than just translated - i.e. I guess I need something considered idiomatic for scenario like this).

Comment: *Could* does not express possibility any more than *can* does. If you want to use *can*, you must change it to *could* here. If you don't want to use *could*, then you certainly cannot use *can*, either.

Comment: Number 1 is OK and so is "could" if you replace "can" in number 2: "He told me that he often felt like he could reach me faster than his own wife" is both correct and idiomatic.

Comment: "I don't want to use 'could', as to my understanding that expresses the possibility – I want to talk about something that did actually happen (and did so often)." But 'feels/felt like' itself expresses doubt / a lack of certainty..

Comment: @RegDwigнt Mark thank you both, this seems definitive so I'd like to accept an answer if somebody would like to post one.

Comment: Aside from tense, the sentence is ambiguous. By "he can/could reach me faster than his own wife" do you mean (1) "he can/could reach me faster than his own wife [can/could reach me]" or (2) "he can/could reach me faster than [he can/could reach] his own wife"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes - but it's possibility in a sense that it often happened or it was true part of the time. I'll try to edit and clarify all that...

Comment: *Could* is ***by far*** the most idiomatic of choices, and your assumption that it only means possibility is incorrect. (It also means ability—and it *is* the past tense of *can*.)